# Javascript function to show text if i input value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, user-input

To the point, if i input value "20" in input field then show message "Thank you".

Here's my HTML Code:

```
<form method="post" action="">
<input type="text" id="nominal" value="">
<input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

Here's my JS Code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var money = 20;

    /* not sure if this is written correctly, but this is supposed to
    check whether the hidden input element value is equal to var money */

    if ($("input[id='nominal']").val() == money )  {

     var h = document.createElement("H1")                // Create a <h1> element
     var t = document.createTextNode("Thank You");     // Create a text node
     h.appendChild(t);                                   // Append the text to <h1>

    };
});
```

i've created one script to fulfill what I need, but not working! what's wrong?

[My JDFIDDLE LINK](https://jsfiddle.net/yt8q7nzn/2/)

Comment: Put you code in `$("#nominal").change(function(){})`

Comment: Add `$('body').append(h);` after `h.appendChild(t);`

Comment: @ThinkDifferent not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to create an event to listening for changes, in this case `changed`. And you can make your code a bit smaller too. ;)

```
$(function() {
    $("#nominal").change(function() {
        if( $(this).val() == 20 )
            $(this).after("<h1>Thank You</h1>");
    });
});
```

Full working exaple with removing the message when value changes again and strict check can be [seen here](https://jsfiddle.net/fma1hyoL/4/).

Comment: Sure it does. For `change` you have to leave focus. If you not want to, use `keyup` too. See here, I created a demo. And a check to prevent double show message: https://jsfiddle.net/fma1hyoL/1/

Comment: This will remove the message too: https://jsfiddle.net/fma1hyoL/4/ Hope this is what you want. Not that I cast the `money` into a string too, because otherwise when the user added spaces, like `20     ` it will show a message too. So it is more strict ...

Answer (score 2):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    var money = 20;
    $("#nominal").change(function() { // take change event of input box
       if ($(this).val() == money )  { // use $(this) to take value
          var h = document.createElement("H1"); // Create a <h1> element
          var t = document.createTextNode("Thank You"); // Create a text node
          h.appendChild(t);      
          $('form').append(h); // append created h1 element in form/html
       } else {
          $('form').find("h1").remove();
       }
     })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="post" action="">
<input type="text" id="nominal" value="">
<input type="button" value="submit" name="submit" id="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: it's work, but when i delete value, the text still showing